# Installing NPM packages conflicting with Node.js 5.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to install npm packages, which i need for my code to work.

However when i try to install **any** npm package, it gives the same error:

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.0.0 (x64) and npm.

C:\Windows\System32>npm install mime
C:\Windows\System32
└── mime@1.3.4

npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON C:\Windows\System32 No license field.

C:\Windows\System32>
```

I have tried re-installing node.js twice, but this didn't work. I've also tried to run it as administrator and install it again, which didn't work.

My classmate also works with node.js, but whenever he isntalled node.js everything worked fine from begin, also installing npm packages.

I'd really appreciate your guys help!

Sincerely,

Ivar

Comment: Blind shot, try running it as administrator.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work either. Thanks though!

Comment: I would not recommend anyone to run node in system32-folder. Ever

Comment: and your classmate uses the same OS? or he/she uses linux/osx?

Comment: @Joakim M: Node automaticly selected this folder. Why don't you recommend it?

mithril_knight: Yes, he uses the same OS.

Comment: @Ivarr08 Since this folder is supposed to be restricted to system files. Do you store your Word-documents and such stuff in there too? It will become impossible to handle which files belong to the operating system and/or programs.

Comment: @JoakimM No, i don't store my Word-documents there. Thanks for the info! Makes sense now :) Although i don't get why node.js automaticly selected this folder?

Comment: Node.js would be ok since that is a program. But when you add modules with npm they get added to your "working" project. Mostly.

Comment: @JoakimM Ahh, so whenever i need to add another module to my node_modules, i have to go to the path of my project, and then install it?

Comment: It's like when working with for example java. You import the libraries you need in one project. You might not need them in another so you don't import them to that. Likle Gemtastic said you CAN install global modules which you are using a lot or so.

Comment: @JoakimM Great example! Now it's clear for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages you're receiving aren't telling you the installation failed, just that you don't have a package.json in the system32 folder. For global install add `-g` to the installation:

```
npm install -g mime --save
```

`--save` just means you save it to your package.json if you're in a root project that has a package.json.

There should be a node_modules in system32 provided you have writing access to it. (sometimes you need to enable that even for admins).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I don't get errors/warnings anymore when i use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it installed package. Check node_modules folder.
It complains that you don't have package.json file and README, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it did actually install. Didn't see that

Comment: Are those missing files (description, repository field, README, license) for npm or for the packages you're trying to install? Is there any way to fix this?